# Running Headless Chrome in Ruby Selenium fails

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless

I have been ruby and selenium for some time now.  Trying to implement headless and it fails.  Even simple example from web. Using Windows 10 on several computers including brand new one with fresh loads applicable resources.
Here is the test code.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: ['headless'])
puts "I'm here"
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, options: options)
puts "Now I'm here"
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')
puts driver.title
driver.quit
```

Here is the result I get.  My applications that run fine normally, will not run headless.

```
I'm here
[0304/084324.450:ERROR:instance.cc(49)] Unable to locate service manifest for metrics
[0304/084324.450:ERROR:service_manager.cc(890)] Failed to resolve service name: metrics

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12145/devtools/browser/626c0a52-00ab-4985-9e1e-d38dfb5161f8
[0304/084324.512:ERROR:instance.cc(49)] Unable to locate service manifest for metrics
[0304/084324.512:ERROR:service_manager.cc(890)] Failed to resolve service name: metrics
[0304/084324.590:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(121)] Failed to launch GPU process.
[0304/084324.590:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1009)] Lost UI shared context.
[0304/084324.807:ERROR:instance.cc(49)] Unable to locate service manifest for metrics
[0304/084324.807:ERROR:service_manager.cc(890)] Failed to resolve service name: metrics
Now I'm here
[0304/084327.694:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://js-sec.indexww.com will be distrusted in the future. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.", source: https://stackoverflow.com/ (0)
Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? - This used to work some months ago but then suddenly stopped, not sure if it was a bundle update or a chrome update that broke it :(

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to execute your `@Tests` in headless mode through *ChromeDriver* you have to pass the argument as follows :

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: ['--headless'])
```

As you are on *Windows 10* while executing `@Tests` in headless mode you also have to pass the following arguments :

- **start-maximized**
- **--disable-gpu**
- **--no-sandbox**

> **Reference** : [*Getting Started with Headless Chrome*](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)

Comment: Thank you.  Double dashes don't change results.  Adding the additional arguments in multiple combinations also did not help.  Used: options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')   to add them
I had previously tried disable-gpu.  Still getting same error

Answer (score -3):

Try with these options, worked for me

'--headless'

'--disable-web-security'

'--incognito'

'--no-sandbox'

'--disable-gpu'

'--window-size=1920,1080'

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. How should OP try it out and why exatcly are you suggesting this?